# Prevent div block from offsetting while resizing window

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a portfolio website and I ran into an issue where my div blocks and content won't stay centralized when resizing the page window. I want the webpage to resize for mobile users and for old square monitors while maintaining the appropriate aspect ratio. I can not seem to figure out the issue. Below is a portion of the website as an example. Any insights?

```css
#timeline {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.99);
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

.job-time {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 540px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-color: gainsboro;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.job-desc {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 110px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.timeline_head {
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="timeline">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="job-time" id="Experience">
        <span class="timeline_head">2017-CURRENT</span>
        <br />
        <p>Geologist II</p>
      </td>
      <td class="job-desc">
        <span class="timeline_head">Current Job</span>
        <br />
        <p>
          Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
          Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. 
          Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. 
          Mauris placerat eleifend leo
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="job-time">
        <span class="timeline_head">2016-2017</span>
        <br />
        <p>Assistant Manager</p>
      </td>
      <td class="job-desc">
        <span class="timeline_head">Old Job 2</span>
        <br />
        <p>
          Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. 
          Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. 
          Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="job-time">
        <span class="timeline_head">2007-2016</span>
        <br />
        <p>Old Job 1</p>
      </td>
      <td class="job-desc">
        <span class="timeline_head">Old Job  1</span>
        <br />
        <p>
          Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. 
          Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. 
          Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. 
          Mauris placerat eleifend leo
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use media queries.

Comment: Please learn about using of media queries in css. I think you are New contributor in Stack Overflow
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries @user2155346